# How to insert a number to a sorted linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have an assignment which I need to write a class which called IntListTwo which represents a two way linked list.
I have this given class which called IntNodeTwo

```
public class IntNodeTwo
{
 private int _num;
 private IntNodeTwo _next, _prev;
 public IntNodeTwo(int n) {
 _num = n;
 _next = null;
 _prev = null;
 }
 public IntNodeTwo(int num, IntNodeTwo n, IntNodeTwo p) {
 _num = num;
 _next = n;
 _prev = p;
 }
 public int getNum() { return _num; }
 public IntNodeTwo getNext() { return _next; }
 public IntNodeTwo getPrev() { return _prev; }
 public void setNum (int n) { _num = n; }
 public void setNext (IntNodeTwo node) { _next = node; }
 public void setPrev (IntNodeTwo node) { _prev = node; }
}
```

And in IntListTwo I have the field "_head" which is the head of the list

That's what I'v tried to do

```
public void addNumber(int num) {

        IntNodeTwo p = new IntNodeTwo(num);

        if (_head == null) {
            _head.setNum(num);
            return;
        }
        if (_head.getNum() > num) {
            IntNodeTwo temp = _head;
            _head = _head.getNext();
            temp = p;
            return;
        }
        else {
            _head = _head.getNext();
            addNumber(num);

        }
    }
```

So for exemple if I have the list {2,5,8,9} and num is 4 I'il get {2,4,5,8,9}

Comment: I suggest using a loop instead of recursion here. You should also use the tips from [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to step through your code to find any problems and understand what you have written so far.

Comment: But how can I use a for loop, I don't know the length of the list

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. A while loop would be more appropriate than a for loop. (And I edited my previous comment.)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips for debugging your code to find what is going wrong. Here are a few things I noticed:

```
if (_head == null) {
            _head.setNum(num);
            return;
        }
```

Since `_head` is `null` here, `_head.setNum(num);` will throw an exception. You need to point it at a new node, instead:

```
_head = p;
```

You change the head of the list every time:

```
_head = _head.getNext();
```

This seems like a problem. How will you know original head of the list when your method finishes? Instead, you should use a temporary node variable, perhaps named `_curr` or something similar.

I think your recursive solution should work after you fix these problems. You might also want to look into an iterative solution with a while loop instead.

If this still isn't working, be sure to read the article I linked above. Learning how to debug code is an important skill.

Comment: I fixed the first problem and know when I print the list. I just get the last number that I'v added. It's I overrid the previous every time I add a new one

Comment: @YftachSrur You also need to set `p.next` to point to the right node.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void addNumber(int num) {

    IntNodeTwo p = new IntNodeTwo(num);

    if (_head == null) {
        _head = new IntNodeTwo(num);
        _head = _tail;
        return;
    }
    if (_head.getNum() > num) {
        IntNodeTwo temp = new IntNodeTwo(num,_head,null);
        temp = _head;

        return;
    }
    else {
        while(num > _head.getNum()) {
            if(_head == null) {
                _head = new IntNodeTwo(num);
                break;
            }
            else {
                p = _head.getNext();
                p = new IntNodeTwo(num);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

That's what I have now. Still doesn't seem to work.